# SQL updating table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----------------------------
1    |  1   |  somestring 12
1    |  2   |  somestring sd
2    |  1   |  somestring gvr
2    |  2   |  somestring 46
3    |  1   |  somestring sdf
3    |  2   |  somestring 4
```

....

i want to UPDATE col3 WHERE col2 = 2

to be a CONCAT of col1 with col3 
and REPLACE all ' ' with '-'.

Also if col1 < 10 add a leading '0' so '1' would be '01'

in total the value of col3 should be '01-somestring-sd'

can someone please help me with the statement?

Comment: UPDATE myTable
   SET col3 = REPLACE(CONCAT(col1, '-', col3), '  ', '-')
   WHERE col2 = 2


figured it out till here now, but dont know how to add the leading '0' :/
(space in the replace statement is cut by SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL3=CONCAT(IF(COL1 < 10,0,''),COL1,REPLACE(COL3, ' ', '-' )) WHERE COL2=2
```

Try above code.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: this was it :)  (adding the missing '-' to the concat)
many thanks

Comment: @poolboy If it's resolved your issue?If yes then accept same.

Answer (score 1):

Create data/insert data

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`col1` INT, `col2` INT, `col3` VARCHAR(255))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'somestring 12'),
    (1, 2, 'somestring sd'),
    (2, 1, 'somestring gvr'),
    (2, 2, 'somestring 46'),
    (3, 1, 'somestring sdf'),
    (3, 2, 'somestring 4')
;
```

**Query**

```
UPDATE 
 Table1
SET
   col3 = 
     CASE
         WHEN col1 < 10
         THEN REPLACE(CONCAT('0', col1, '-', col3), ' ', '-')
         ELSE REPLACE(CONCAT(col1, '-', col3), ' ', '-')
     END
WHERE
 col2 = 2
```

**Result**

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: UPDATE Table1 SET col3 = CASE WHEN col1 < 10 THEN REPLACE(CONCAT('0', col1, '-', col3), ' ', '-') ELSE REPLACE(CONCAT(col1, '-',...

3 row(s) affected
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

**Result**

```
  col1    col2  col3              
------  ------  ------------------
     1       1  somestring 12     
     1       2  01-somestring-sd  
     2       1  somestring gvr    
     2       2  02-somestring-46  
     3       1  somestring sdf    
     3       2  03-somestring-4
```

Answer (score 0):

just use Concat and Replace

```
update table_name as t set t.col3 = 
CONCAT(if(t.col1<10,0,''),t.col1,REPLACE(t.col‌​3,' ','-')) where 
t.col2 =2;
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Update table1 
set 
col3 = concat((case when col1>10 then '0'+col1 else col1 end),'-',REPLACE(COL3, ' ','-' ))
where col2=2
```